# Closest path between points on grid

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, grid-layout

I have grid dimension 2000x2000. I have some points stored on grid and I want to connect some of them, but connection need to be closest path from one to another.
I have :

`private static readonly Dictionary<double,Point> ExistingPoints = new Dictionary<double, Point>();
 private static Point[,] gridMatrix = new Point[200, 200];`

where `ExistingPoints` is dictionary of points that are placed on grid and `gridMatrix` contains same points from dictionary, but his `row` and `column` are x and y from point divided by 10 so it can be represented on grid.

So how can I find closest path from one point to another?

**EDIT**

Path can only go on grid, meaning it can go on lines only, it  can't be straight line, so when I need to go up/ down/ left/ right it need to be on 90 degrees

Comment: Are there obstacles in the way or can the connection lines be straight lines?

Comment: @Eric.Volli my mistake, it need to go on grid lines, it can't be inside tile, I edited post

Comment: Are there any blocked lines or "grid parts"?

Comment: @Eric.Volli Nope, whole grid is available, only thing that is required is that path need to go on grid lines

Comment: okey. In that case the solution is quite simple. If you can only move in straight lines and there are no obstacles than you can simply move into the y-direction until the y-value euqals the target points value and then move into the right x direction. Or you move in a "stair" pattern. Do you need any help to implement that?

Comment: @Eric.Volli right now I am trying something like that, I compare first.Y and second.Y and if second is greater I add 10 to my first.Y, I still don;t know if this 'algorithm' will work. If u have something finished already, I will be more than glad to try it

Comment: @Eric.Volli yep, this works, but I get straight line, I need to figure out how to draw line only on grid lines

Comment: You will have to record all visited points and then draw many lines in steps. I wrote an answer for that.

Comment: @Eric.Volli my mistake was that I went to "stair" pattern, then I didn't have information that I needed to draw line, I get the idea of ur answer, I will test it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey as we said in the comments I would do this:

```
List<Point> path = new List<Point>();
Point startingPoint = new Point(1000, 1000);
Point targetPoint = new Point(500, 500);
Point currentPos = startingPoint;

//Level in Y
while (currentPos.Y != targetPoint.Y)
{
     path.Add(new Point(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y);
     currentPos.Y += (currentPos.Y > targetPoint.Y ? -1 : 1);
}
//Level in X
while(currentPos.X != targetPoint.X)
{
     path.Add(new Point(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y);
     currentPos.X += (currentPos.X > targetPoint.X ? -1 : 1);
}

//Draw the lines in steps
for (int i = 0; i < path.Count()-1; i++)
{
     DrawLineBetween(path[i], path[i + 1]);
}
DrawLineBetween(path.Last(), targetPoint);
```

I did not test the code but it compiles and should work in theory. The Method `DrawLineBetween`still has to be implemented of course but I guess you have something in place here.

You could, of course, combine the X and Y leveling in one loop and then go in a "stair" pattern.

Comment: There is some minor errors, but I rate idea, simple, ty

Comment: Okey great. Could you point out the errors so that I can edit the answer? I don't want wrong code being online.

Comment: U always add `currentPos` and that is reference to existing object, so u will have List of same objects, and when u change X or Y on one object, "others" in list will get modified also. Second error is that we don't add last item to list, because when second `WHILE` is finished, we don't save last Point, so we won't have information about that last coordinates in our list